# How can I effectively hide my macbook while traveling to prevent theft

Tags: security, macbook-pro

I will be taking my Macbook Pro Retina for a backpacking trip and will be working from public places (i.e. coffee shops, public squares) for a while. I am quite concerned though, that it will be stolen.

Aside from the obvious precautions for theft, like not leaving it out of eyesight, backing everything up to a second disk, encrypting stuff, firmware password, setting up prey etc. I am looking for a way to disguise the machine as something more undesirable than a macbook.

Of course there is always the [Book Cover disguise](http://twelvesouth.com/products/bookbook/) or the option to cover the whole thing in [conference stickers](http://blogof.francescomugnai.com/2009/07/60-sticker-plastered-apple-laptops/) so it looks like a piece of trash, but maybe you guys know something equally suitable for this purpose?

Comment: I like your piece of trash idea :)

Comment: A Lot of photographers use black gaff-a tape on their cameras. The one problem doing it on a Mac. Is I suspect it will ruin the finish.. You could put a MS Windows logo on it. No will touch it then ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Searching on the web for "laptop skin" or "removable laptop skin" would provide you a list of designers and sellers for laptop skins. Buy a boring laptop skin and use it on your MacBook Pro.

Some sites for laptop skins (in no particular order):

- [CafePress](http://www.cafepress.com/)
- [Gelaskins](http://www.gelaskins.com/)
- [Zazzle](http://www.zazzle.com/)
- [DecalGirl](http://www.decalgirl.com/)
- [Skinit](http://www.skinit.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [this little program](http://ialertu.en.softonic.com/mac), to scare ppl off, but nothing is safer than hanging on to it.

That program called iAlertU does following:

Once activated, it will trigger an alarm as soon as your MacBook is moved or your keyboard/trackpad is touched.

It can also automatically take a snapshot of the robber with the iSight camera and send it automatically by email. ?? at least you will know what the face was looking like :)

It could be disturbing however in a conference rooms, while you are trying to turn it off.